# How to rename levels of a factor?

Tags: r, r-factor

I have a 5 dataframes containing multiple variables (110) in three different languages and I'm pretty new to using R. I'm recoding the factors to numbers that I can merge all of the dataframes in the end. With most of the factors it simply worked, except for the following sentence. I suspect that the dot in "ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384" are confusing but I can't get rid of it

```
data$B1aC <- as.factor(data$B1aC)
levels(data$B1aC)
summary(data$B1aC)
data$B1aC <- factor(data$B1aC, levels = c("Einsatz auf Wunsch des 
Bewohners/der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem/der dazu 
urteilsfähigen Bewohner/-in","Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner/-in, alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt","Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt, nicht alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt"),labels = c("1", "2", "3"))
table(data$B1aC)
```

When I display the transformed data, I lose numbers 2 and 3 (both having a dot in their level). Does anyone know what I can do?

I'm using Rstudio on Apple (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) with R 3.3.3 running.

this is the output for *table()*

```
table(data$B1aC)

Einsatz auf Wunsch des Bewohners/der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem/der dazu urteilsfähigen Bewohner/-in 
                                                                                                                  1 
      Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner/-in, alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt 
                                                                                                                  1 
                    Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt, nicht alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt 
                                                                                                                  1 

summary(data$B1aC)
Einsatz auf Wunsch des Bewohners/der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem/der dazu urteilsfähigen Bewohner/-in 
                                                                                                                  1 
      Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner/-in, alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt 
                                                                                                                  1 
                    Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt, nicht alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt 
                                                                                                                  1 
                                                                                                               NA's 
                                                                                                                 97
```

I had to convert the strings to numbers because the data frames are in 3 different languages - merging then would confuse me, because I'm not too familiar with all the languages.

after transforming the data:

```
data$B1aC <- factor(data$B1aC, levels = c("Einsatz auf Wunsch des Bewohners/der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem/der dazu urteilsfähigen Bewohner/-in",
                                                    "Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner/-in, alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt",
                                                    "Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt, nicht alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt"),
                         labels = c("1", "2", "3"))
table(data$B1aC)

1 2 3 
1 0 0
```

Comment: "I'm recoding the factors to numbers that I can merge all of the dataframes in the end." - this isn't necessary because you can merge on character variables. Can you describe what you mean by merging here, and include your output?

Comment: have you tried `levels(data$B1aC) <- c("Einsatz....","Einsatz...","Kontext...")` ?

Comment: I believe the parentheses need to be escaped, thus "\\\(" and "\\\)".

Comment: as well as all the punctuation

Comment: Please show the output from `table()`. Escaping punctuation or parentheses shouldn't be necessary because `levels()` involves no pattern matching. The vector assigned is "a vector of character strings with length at least the number of levels of `x`, or a named list specifying how to rename the levels."

Comment: Thank you for all your help!! 
I added the table output but I didn't come forward with any of the suggestions. I can't merge the character variables because they are in 3 different languages (german, french & italian), thats why I switch to numbers to combine the answers. I can't merge at the moment, because I don't have all the data yet - I started by cleaning/preparing this dataset (which is 1 of 5) and got the problem with the punctuation.
I don't get any error msg but I loose two cases..

Answer (score 1):

Given your `text` you can get rid of the punctuations as follows:

```
  text<-c("Einsatz auf Wunsch des Bewohners/der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem/der dazu urteilsfähigen Bewohner/-in","Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner/-in, alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt","Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt, nicht alle Bedingungen (ESG Art. 383 und Art. 384) sind erfüllt")

  text<-gsub(pattern = "[[:punct:]]"," ",text,perl=T)
```

Thus yielding:

```
> text

[1] "Einsatz auf Wunsch des Bewohners der Bewohnerin oder im Einverständnis mit dem der dazu urteilsfähigen Bewohner  in"
[2] "Einsatz bei dazu nicht urteilsfähiger Bewohner  in  alle Bedingungen  ESG Art  383 und Art  384  sind erfüllt"      
[3] "Kontext ist noch nicht geklärt  nicht alle Bedingungen   ESG Art  383 und Art  384   sind erfüllt"
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if you're trying to relabel your factor so that each level has a numeric label, instead of the existing text label. This *does not* require carefully replicating each of the existing labels, or clobbering their punctuation toward this end.

Factors inherit from integer and `as.numeric` gives you their numeric representation:

```
data(warpbreaks)
table(warpbreaks$wool)
# 
#  A  B 
# 27 27 
table(as.numeric(warpbreaks$wool))
# 
#  1  2 
# 27 27
```

At this point, if you really wanted, you could relabel the factor numerically (below), but from your mention of needing to merge dataframes by this variable, I can't think of why this would be desirable.

```
warpbreaks$wool <- factor(warpbreaks$wool, labels =
  unique(as.numeric(warpbreaks$wool)))

table(warpbreaks$wool)
# 
#  1  2 
# 27 27
```